# Aggregate pipeline to select all users not found in another documents array

Tags: mongodb

I am wondering if it is possible to use a pipeline to select all users from a user collection that don't exist in an array found in another collection. I have two collections: `users` and `events`. I want to get all users that are not already added to an event.

User Schema

```
{
   _id: ObjectId
   name: string
}
```

Event Schema

```
{
   _id: ObjectId
   name: string
   users: ObjectId[]
}
```

I'm fumbling around with lookups, unwinds, and matches, and know this can be simple without a pipeline, but I want to make sure pagination works and that I don't load 100s of users into RAM (assuming a pipeline is a more efficient way? Maybe I am wrong and the mongodb server would also have to load everything during aggregation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution with lookup.

```js
pipeline = [
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      let: { user_ids: "$users" },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $not: { $in: ["$_id", "$$user_ids"] } } } },
      ],
      as: "AbsentUsers",
    },
  },
];
```

See it in the [Mongodb Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/s0wMSuM2qkW) and kindly refer to the docs yourself.

Comment: Nice, I had no idea you could do mulitple collections in playground. So would mongodb and a pipeline do a better (faster, less ram, less cpu.. etc) job than me if I were to just first get all users from the events array and then pass that as a `$nin` match param?

Comment: May be, I don't actually know! Feel free to do your own experiment :)